# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIsAuth')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, state

im gettin error: "Login.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIsAuth')"

Here is my Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { auth, provider } from '../firebaseconf';
import { signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login({ setIsAuth }) {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const singInWithGoogle = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
            localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
            setIsAuth(true);
            navigate("/");
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={singInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
        </div>
    );

}
export default Login;
```

And there is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/main.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import CreatePost from './pages/CreatePost';
import Login from './pages/Login';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuth: false,
      setIsAuth: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/createpost"> Create New Post</Link>
          {!this.state.isAuth && <Link to="/login">Login</Link>}
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login setIsAuth={this.state.setIsAuth} />} />
          <Route path="/createpost" element={<CreatePost />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

i think that i defined it already in App.js in constructor, looking up for ur help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `login.js` you're using `setIsAuth` as if it were a function but is not a function, it's a variable setted as `false` in your `App.js`. To change the value of `this.state.setIsAuth` you should do something like this :

```
App.js

signIn = () => {
  this.setState({ setIsAuth: true });
}

<Route path="/login" element={<Login setIsAuth={this.signIn} />} />


Login.js

signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
  localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
  setIsAuth();
  navigate("/");
});
```

Comment: ok now its redirecting me to Home after login, but "Login" in navigation bar is still visible so it looks like the state didnt change

Comment: and also i dont get error but "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIsAuth')" is in the console

Comment: ok, i changed it to "{!this.state.setIsAuth && <Link to="/login">Login</Link>}" and now it works, i still got that information in console but everythink works fine, thanks

Comment: i also deleted isAuth because it looks for me like its useless